# Configuring docker to communicate over the network

Tags: networking, docker, ssh, docker-network

I have remote machine. I enter into it in two steps:

```
1) ssh -A login@server.com
```

Then inside this machine I enter into my remote machine:

```
2)ssh -A mymachine
```

This remote machine doesn't have a public `IP` which I can specify in `DOCKER_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx`.

How can I configure my docker in such way that my laptop would have a `docker client` and that remote machine would have `docker` `server` daemon?

Comment: So is the first machine (server.com) public and is this where you want to run the docker client? Or are you trying to connect from your local machine through the remote (server.com) machine to the private server's docker host? Just need some more information to help you out

Comment: @Dockstar Yes, the second variant is my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker client/server API needs a reachable API. Just as you can't run a web server on mymachine and access it with a web browser on your laptop, you can't configure DOCKER_HOST without an IP you can reach.

Your options that I can think of include:

- Run your commands remotely, either on mymachine or on server.com.
- Setup a VPN that gives your laptop an IP that can reach mymachine
- Use ssh port forwarding to make a tunnel which you can point your DOCKER_HOST to. e.g. `ssh -L 2376:mymachine:2376 login@server.com` and then `export DOCKER_HOST=localhost:2376` (I haven't tested this, and it requires sshd to permit the option).

Comment: If I run `ssh -L 2376:mymachine:2376 login@server.com` I only enter into server.com console. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You'll need to do some more research on how ssh port forwarding works. [Here's a question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115897/171859) that may help.

Comment: The third option helped me.